# Scrapy renaming images

Tags: python, scrapy

I am running a Scrapy CrawlSpider to download images from a website.

Using the Pipeline:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.pipelines.images import ImagesPipeline
from PIL import Image

class XPipeline(ImagesPipeline):

    def set_filename(self, response):
        return 'full/{0}.jpg'.format(response.meta['title'][0])

    def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
        for image_url in item['image_urls']:
            yield scrapy.Request(image_url, meta={'title': item['Sku']})

    def get_images(self, response, request, info):
        for key, image, buf in super(XPipeline, self).get_images(response, request, info):
            key = self.set_filename(response)
        yield key, image, buf
```

This works well when there is only one 'image_urls' per product page, however, it is often the case that a product page may have multiple product images.

Also how can I modify pipeline to add an integer value to modified image title?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can track both the image_url and the index of the image_url in the for loop in get_media_requests and append the index to title, like so:

```
def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
    for i, image_url in enumerate(item['image_urls']):
        yield scrapy.Request(image_url, meta={'title_' + i: item['Sku']})
```

[Enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) is a Python function that wraps a sequence or iterator, like a list and returns an iterator of tuples with value (index, list[index]). For example:

```
abc = ['a', 'b', 'c']
print list(enumerate(abc))
# Output: [(0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c')]
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be something like `meta={'title': item['Sku'] + i}` instead? otherwise, you're changing the title key and `response.meta['title'][0]` (why the `[0]` by the way?) in `set_filename` would not work.

Comment: @paultrmbrth, ah, I assumed the poster meant the 'image_urls' in the get_media_requests function, but you might be right!